# can't uninstall python3 in macOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, uninstallation, reinstall

I am having trouble with my current python, so I wanted to uninstall my python and install the latest version. I installed with homebrew, so I uninstalled it with homebrew and reinstalled python 3.8.1 with the installer from the official site. Python3.8 was installed, but my python3 was not upgraded.

```
 ~ which python3                                      
/usr/bin/python3
 ~ python3 --version                                  
Python 3.7.3
```

I know I'm not supposed to(and I can't) manually delete things inside `/usr/bin`. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: What does your `PATH` look like? `echo $PATH`. Likely `/usr/local/bin` simply isn't in it and/or `/usr/bin` has higher priority.

Comment: `~ echo $PATH 
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:/usr/local/opt/fzf/bin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin`
Sry I don’t understand. Can you explain it again?

Comment: That looks okay… what does `which -a python3` give you? Does it find `/usr/local/bin/python3`?

Comment: it gives me ```/usr/bin/python3```

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/python3` actually exist? Can you execute `/usr/local/bin/python3 -V`?

Comment: ```/usr/local/bin/python3.8``` exists no `/usr/local/bin/python3`?

Comment: Well, there's your problem…!?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure if there's a reason for brew not to create a `python3` symlink as well and whether that's worth fixing. Using `python3.8` instead of `python3` should at least work. If you want to dig into why `/usr/local/bin/python3` wasn't created by brew, you should post a more detailed and specific question about that. In practice you should be using virtualenvs a lot, so the entire issue largely becomes moot once you've created a virtualenv for your project and just use `python` within it.

Comment: Got it. Thx a bunch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you installed Python with **homebrew** it told you this:

> Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
>   `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been
>   installed into   /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin

If you need a reminder, post install, you will get the same message if you run:

```
brew info python
```

It says *"unversioned links are in `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin`"*. That means, if you want to run Python without specifying the version, i.e. if you want to type this:

```
python
```

and this:

```
pip
```

to start Python 3 and its corresponding `pip`, you need to make sure your `PATH` has `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin` at the start, i.e.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Any reasons behind it? Why can /usr/local/bin has all the unversioned links? Potentially, conflicts with other system components?

Answer (score 1):

I could not uninstall the python3 in `/usr/bin` but found a workaround to give the python3 in `/usr/loca/bin` precedence by setting the PATH env variable as `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`. This gives binaries in `/usr/local/bin` precedence. Not a full fledged solution, but got me moving.