# How to revert to Python3.8 on my Mac using Homebrew?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, homebrew, zsh, python-3.8

please see this question: [How to default Python3.8 on my Mac using Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60453261/how-to-default-python3-8-on-my-mac-using-homebrew)

I'm trying to accomplish the same thing. I brew installed python and that gave me the latest 3.9; however, I would like to use 3.8 to maintain dependencies.

When i check terminal for the version of python the result is always the macOS default of 2.7.

I've used this method above and many other methods, but I am new to homebrew and zsh and I have not found a work around.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are methods that allow you to switch the version of Python you need [per project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138280/easiest-way-to-use-python-3-6-and-3-7-on-same-computer). Would this help?

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to use `pyenv` to manage different python versions in your local.

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.7.9
pyenv install 3.8.6
```

Then you can control machine default by using `pyenv global x.x.x`

```
pyenv global 3.8.6
```