# Can't find Python on MACBOOK M1 even python being installed

Tags: python, reactjs, npm, apple-m1

I'm getting the error
**"Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable"**

when running the **npm install** command on a React project in Visual Studio Code on **Macbook M1**.

Python is installed with brew but it still gives the error:

> brew install python

> Warning: python@3.11 3.11.2_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
> To reinstall 3.11.2_1, run:
> brew reinstall python@3.11

But I can`t use python version command

> ▶ python --version
>
> zsh: command not found: python

Errors

> gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
> gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
>
> ...
>
> gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
> gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python

Package.json

```
{ "name": "my-project",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^18.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^2.1.0",
        "@devexpress/dx-react-core": "^2.7.5",
        "@devexpress/dx-react-grid": "^2.7.5",
        "@devexpress/dx-react-grid-bootstrap4": "^2.7.5",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "cpf-cnpj-validator": "^1.0.3",
        "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
        "custom-error": "^0.2.1",
        "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
        "draft-js-export-html": "^1.4.1",
        "draft-js-import-html": "^1.4.1",
        "firebase": "^8.4.1",
        "firebase-tools": "^7.16.2",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "google-maps-react": "^2.0.6",
        "install": "^0.13.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "js-base64": "^2.6.4",
        "js-md5": "^0.7.3",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "qrcode.react": "^0.9.3",
        "react": "^16.14.0",
        "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.3",
        "react-confirm-alert": "^2.7.0",
        "react-currency-input": "^1.3.6",
        "react-datepicker": "^2.16.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
        "react-file-viewer": "^1.2.1",
        "react-filter-search": "^1.0.11",
        "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
        "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
        "react-intl-currency-input": "^0.2.6",
        "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.1",
        "react-loading-skeleton": "^2.2.0",
        "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
        "react-notification-alert": "0.0.12",
        "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.3.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
        "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.18",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "^3.4.4",
        "react-select": "^3.2.0",
        "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "valid-url": "^1.0.9"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "deploy:dev": "firebase deploy --only hosting:ingresso-gospel-dev",
        "deploy": "firebase deploy",
        "build:deploy": "npm run build && node node_modules/react-build-cache && firebase deploy"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1",
        "react-build-cache": "^1.1.4"
      }
    }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59748653/2836621

Comment: The export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH not worked

Comment: Did you run `brew info python` ?

Comment: Just use python3 instead of python. Or create an alias for it.

Comment: The dev dependencies need the name python, the question solution worked for now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to use pyenv because python 2.x was having problems with  macbook

Solution that worked for me

> brew install pyenv

> pyenv install 2.7.18

> pyenv global 2.7.18

> eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

> source ~/.zprofile

and then the npm install worked fine